# joining tables without showing duplicate values as it relates to the other

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables; table1, table2, however table1 only has 1 record and table2 has 3 records im trying to join the tables so that it only shows one record from table 1 but all three from table2 without duplicating the values from table1

```
SELECT * from table1 a
inner  join table2 b on
a.table1_id=b.table2_id
```

I have tried this but it still return a duplicate of the row in table1 and as I stated I tryin to get the 1 row from table1 joining with the three rows from tabl2 without showing the duplicates from table1

Comment: Do you want one row or three rows total?

Comment: THis question is _very_ hard to parse.  Can you please go back and add punctuation, proper capitalization, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to pull out one row from one table and three rows from another table on a `JOIN`. What would such a result set even *look* like? The closest you can get is to `GROUP` by `table1.id` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` the `table2` values.

E.g:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id SEPARATOR ', '),
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM
    t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
GROUP BY
    t1.id
```

Comment: so what about the linking of the tables interms of foreign keys i want to join the tables where there is actually a link between them, using the foreign keys

Comment: Ok thanks I will Most definitely try this and let you know if this solved the problem

Comment: It works but everything comes in 1 row, what I am tryin to get is still the 3 rows but to display what is in table1 only once with no duplicates of table 1 in the remaining 2 rows but have the various rows from tabl2 two bein displayed, example table1 information to the left, should only b 1 row on information however to the right 3 rows of information

Comment: That's impossible. You either have three rows or one row. You can't have one complete row and two half rows.

Answer (score 0):

When you join two table, the amount of records that you get will be the number of records based on the join and where criteria.  IE, if your table has 3 records joined to a table with one record, you are going to get 3 records.  If you need ONLY one record, do not join the values, CONCAT the values of the 3 records with a SUBSELECT to the first table without a join.

Comment: I do need 3 records I just dont want the record in table 1 to be duplicated, table1 has 1, and table2 has 3 different corresponding records so I want the 1 record to be on the left from table1 and the 3 records from table2 to be on the right of the join however i do not want table1 records to be duplicated 2 more times in correspondence to the other 2 records from table 2

Comment: Then do not use a JOIN.  There is no way around it from the database layer if you are going to use a single sql statement.  What environment are you using? java, c# ...?